# Making a function with adding up the numbers between a set of numbers

Tags: php

I have to make a function that works like this:
telOp(2, 5) => 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 14
Or
telOp(1, 6) => 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21

I have tried a few things but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried making a while loop in the function:

```
<?php
function telOp($getal1, $getal2){
    while ($getal1 <= $getal2){
        echo $getal1++;
    }
}
$resultaat = telOp(5, 10);
print ($resultaat);
```

Now this will print the numbers from 5 through 10 but I can't seem to make it work that they add up.

I have also tried simply adding the numbers up with a return statement but combining the 2 doesn't seem to work.:

```
<?php
function telOp($getal1, $getal2){
    while ($getal1 <= $getal2){
        echo $getal1++;
    }
    $resultaat = ($getal1 + $getal2);
    return $resultaat;
}
$resultaat = telOp(5, 10);
print ($resultaat);
```

I am new to php so any tips would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are adding the numbers outside of the while loop. Also you shouldn't add the upper bound always. Here's the fixed code.

```
<?php
function telOp($getal1, $getal2){
    $resultaat=0;
    while ($getal1 <= $getal2){
        
        $resultaat = ($resultaat+ $getal1);
        $getal1++;
    }
    
    return $resultaat;
}
$resultaat = telOp(5, 10);
print ($resultaat);
```

Also, here's a small hint to making this run way faster. in order to achieve what you are trying, you don't need to iterate through all the numbers, you can just use a math formula that says that the sum of the first n numbers is n*(n+1)/2. So essentially if you have two numbers a and b, and want to compute a+(a+1)+...+(b-1)+b, you can just compute the sum of the first b numbers with that formula, and subtract the sum of the first a-1 numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me understand it way better.

Comment: @Cyten In  other words, use the sum formula for first n numbers in an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 0):

You are fairly close. You need to add the numbers up in the telOp function. That can be done in the following way:

```
<?php
function telOp($getal1, $getal2){
    $result = 0;
    while ($getal1 <= $getal2){
        $result += $getal1++;
    }
    return $result;
}
$resultaat = telOp(5, 10);
echo ($resultaat);
```